# How can I get my Steam Cloud saves without installing the game?

Tags: steam, saints-row-iv, steam-cloud

I currently started a new game on Saints Row: Gat out of Hell from GOG. Since you can [import your character](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/import-boss-from-sr4-to-gooh.14763/page-3#post-98663) from the old Saints Row 4 savegames, I need my data that is stored on Steam Cloud.

Because I don't want to download the whole 9+1 GB of SR4 on Steam just for the saves: How can I get my savegames stored on Steam Cloud without having the game installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should now be possible through https://help.steampowered.com/en/accountdata thanks to GDPR, at least in part. Specifically the [Steam Cloud](https://store.steampowered.com/account/remotestorage) link under the section "Uploaded Data".

Answer (score 3):

You can download the files one at a time from here:
https://store.steampowered.com/account/remotestorage

Or you could just download the game, synchronize it and then move the files.